# Как выбрать случайный элемент из списка с исключением python

Tags: python, массивы, случайные-числа

Всем привет есть такой код

```
mas = [sa, as, qw, re, bew, uf, yt]
lv1 = random.choice(mas)
lv2 = random.choice(mas) #lv2 не должно быть равно lv1
```

как сделать чтобы элемент выбирался с исключением

Comment: Под `sa, as, qw...` понимаются отдельные переменные или строки?

Comment: переменные с численными значениями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть несколько вариантов, можете выбирать какой удобно:

1. Удаляем из исходного списка выбранный ранее элемент при помощи [`remove()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/list.remove/):

```py
mas = [sa, as, qw, re, bew, uf, yt]
lv1 = random.choice(mas)
mas.remove(lv1)                      # убираем из mas элемент, уже выбранный и помещённый в lv1
lv2 = random.choice(mas)             # выборка из всех элементов, кроме lv1
```

2. Создаём новый список, в который помещаем все элементы, кроме выбранного (положим, что все элементы уникальны) — это называется созданием списка через [генератор](https://pythoner.name/list-comprehension):

```py
mas = [sa, as, qw, re, bew, uf, yt]
lv1 = random.choice(mas)
mas1 = [elem for elem in mas if elem != lv1] # в новый список помещаем такие elem из старого списка,
                                             # которые не равны lv1
lv2 = random.choice(mas1)                    # выборка из нового списка mas1
```

Answer (score 3):

Первый вариант: Брать случайный индекс и "pop" нужный элемент.

```py
>>> import random
>>> array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> array.pop(random.randrange(len(array)))
15
>>> array.pop(random.randrange(len(array)))
13
>>> array 
[10, 11, 12, 14, 16]
>>>
```

Второй вариант: Перемешать список, и потом брать по порядку элементы. Или же по индексу.

```py
>>> import random
>>> array = [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> random.shuffle(array)
>>> for element in array:
...     print(element)
... 
13
16
12
11
15
14
10
>>> element1 = array[0]
>>> element2 = array[1]
```